# opening windows with different delegates

Tags: macos, cocoa

I currently have a situation where I have a button in window1 of delegate1 that when clicked should run a method to open window2 of delegate2 and do some other stuff:

```
-(void)start {
        [window2 makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
        //do some other stuff to window2
}
```

This certainly works if both windows have the same delegate but what if window1 has delegate1 and window2 has delegate2?  I can't figure out how to get this working

In delegate1.m I have:

```
 delegate2 *letsStart = [[delegate2 alloc] init];
 [letsStart start];
```

Thanks in advance (smashing head against wall)

Comment: What class are the delegates and how do you create the window?

Comment: delegate1 is:  `NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate> ` and delgate2 is `NSObject <NSWindowDelegate>`  window1 is created like: `IBOutlet NSWindow *window1;` in delegate1 and window2: `@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window2;` in delegate2

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: `start` is located in delegate2... so when delegate1 calls `[letsStart start]`  `window2` is not activated and brought to the front.  I think it has to do with the fact that in delegate1 a new instance of delegate 2 is created that is not bound to `window2` so when `start` is called it has no connection to the new instance of `window2` so it can't operate on it.   I just don't know how to set this all up...

Comment: The easiest way is to put delegate2 in the XIB (Object, change the class). Add an outlet in delegate1 and connect delegate2. Connect window2 to delegate2 in the XIB.